# How can i get a Pipeline view in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Can any one let me know is there a possibility that i can see all the list of steps that are involved in build and release can be seen in a pipeline view in VSTS (Same as the pipeline view in jenkins ? If so can some one point me to the right documents ? how to create the pipeline view ?)

I wanted pipeline view as shown below for every application that i build. before i run the pipeline.

[image: jenkins pipeline view which i wanted the same in TFS]

Comment: are you looking to see this in the web interface or pull the data using an API?

Comment: I wanted to see this sort of web interface for build and release

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t such view in VSTS build/release, you need to check the detail by open specified build/release definition.

Build Definition:

[image]

Release Definition (click the link (e.g. 1 phase, 1 task) to check detail tasks):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the web interface, go to the `Build and Release` section. Click on the Build you want to see the pipeline for, then, next to the `Queue new build` button, you will see a link to Edit. Clicking on this will bring you to a view of all the steps of the build.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have attached a pipeline view from jenkins . Is there some thing like that which i can see for every application before i run it ?